# SVG loading Slowly in Safari iOS 6

Tags: svg, ios6, mobile-safari

We have some svg files that are loading incredibly slowly in Safari in iOS 6 (the browser hangs for about a minute or so when loading the file.  This is browsing directly to the svg file, no javascript or external code.

The same file when loading in Safari in iOS 5 takes only a second or 2 to load.  Has anyone else run across this issue in iOS 6 or know of any svg elements that may cause this to happen in iOS 6?

Comment: Mobile Safari on iOS6 now supports filters, perhaps your SVG file has filters that used to be ignored in iOS5?

Comment: The issue had to do with the way the original svg file was created.  Originally each object had a stroke & stoke width defined (we were using a 3rd party app).  That was fine until iOS 5.  We are now defining that info with css at the group level (svg now created with an in-house app) & everything seems to be working well.